# Ios Cordova App Crashes while playing audio

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

I am creating a game in Cordova.
It crashes while playing the audio. I need to play one sound as background music and other one as game sound(On button click some audio). I implemented like the below code but it crashes in iPad

```
<audio id="musicSound" src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mp3" ></audio>
   <audio id="joinSound" src="audio/join.mp3" type="audio/mp3" ></audio>

playAudio('musicSound');

function playAudio(id) {
var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);
var url = audioElement.getAttribute('src');
mediaFlag = "true";
my_media = new Media(url,
                         // success callback
                         function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
                         // error callback
                         function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); }
                         );
// Play audio
my_media.play();
}


function pauseAudio() {
if (my_media) {
    my_media.pause();
}
}

function stopAudio() {
mediaFlag = "false";
if (my_media) {
    my_media.stop();
   // my_media.release();
}
}
```